# redirect everything after the root url to subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i would like to use .htaccess to rewrite every subfolder or page existing or non existing to a specific subfolder. For example www.domain.com/idontexist to redirect to www.domain.com/mainfolder. Basically all requests should to to /mainfolder and return a status of 200.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !mainfolder /mainfolder [L,NC]
```